# Error for Apache2.2.15 configuration with PHP5

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am trying to configure **apache 2.2.15** with **php5** in my linux system. I have installed both of them. But when I added **libphp5.so** module in `httpd.conf` of apache, it has given  the following error while starting the server:

> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: ap_unixd_config

Can anybody tell me how to fix this, as I tried every possible solution by googling it but in vain?

Comment: which linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Some newer PHP versions may not be compatible with **Apache2.2**. This error occurs because the function `ap_unixd_config` is in Apache2.2 still called `unixd_config`.

Try to use **Apache2.4** if you need to use this PHP version, otherwise you can use an older version of PHP.

Comment: yeah. came across this when using apache 2.2 and libphp55-php5.so

Comment: Does it means, that the configuration incompatible at all? I've built `php 5.5.13` from source and trying to use it with `apache2 2.2.22-1`. Meanwhile there is `php 5.5.10` for such an apache version In http://snapshot.debian.org/.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens on Arch Linux when one doesn't upgrade Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4. So if you are using Arch Linux you need to downgrade `php-apache` package to the version that works for you. `php-apache-5.5.8-1` is still OK, whereas `5.5.11-1` is not.

Answer (score 0):

On RedHat Apache2 and PHP installation is done by issuing the following commands (as root):

```
yum install httpd httpd-devel php php-mysql php-common php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-devel php-xml
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```

That's all. (I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/quick-n-easy-lamp-server-centos-rhel).) You may add or remove some php extensions to or from the list of packages to be installed if so desired.

Comment: I have done it manually as yum is disabled for me. I have followed following link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php. Is there any alternative?

Comment: you want to run apache2 as non root user? If so, I expect that there is more configuration during compilation process is required